# Java create a checksum in ASCII

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, ascii

I have to sum the ASCII in a string and put the last character of the sum in a byte to send with the string on Bluetooth.

```
es: String s = "R002" 
sum: R+0+0+2 = 000000000000000000000000000000000000c3a4 = ä
```

I try to send `R(52)+0(30)+0(30)+2(32)+¤(a4)`
but I send    `R(52)+0(30)+0(30)+2(32)+Ä(c3)+¤(a4)` ,

In which way can i send ¤ without Ä?

```
the code:

        String pergolato = "ä";
        String pesto= String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, pergolato.substring(0, 1).getBytes(/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/)));

        int zaino = Integer.parseInt(pesto, 16);
        char c = (char) (zaino & 0xff);

        String sum="R002"+c;
        for(int i=0;i<sum.length();i++){
            String s= String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, sum.substring(i, i+1).getBytes(/*YOUR_CHARSET?*/)));
            Log.i(TAG, sum.charAt(i)+" "+s);
        }

the LogCat:

R 0000000000000000000000000000000000000052

0 0000000000000000000000000000000000000030

0 0000000000000000000000000000000000000030

2 0000000000000000000000000000000000000032

¤ 000000000000000000000000000000000000c2a4
```

Comment: `Ä` and `¤` aren't ASCII.

Comment: sorry I have to send a hexadecimal

Comment: Standard ASCII characters range from 0 to 127.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code a bit for my purpose.
Results with different encoding :

`UTF-8` --> ¤ 000000000000000000000000000000000000c2a4

`UTF-16` --> ¤ 00000000000000000000000000000000feff00a4

`UTF-32` --> ¤ 00000000000000000000000000000000000000a4

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pergolato = "ä";
        String pesto= String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, pergolato.getBytes()));

        int zaino = Integer.parseInt(pesto, 16);
        char c = (char) (zaino & 0xff);

        String sum="R002"+c;
        for(int i=0;i<sum.length();i++){
            String s= String.format("%040x", new BigInteger(1, sum.substring(i, i+1).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-32"))));
            System.out.println(sum.charAt(i)+" "+s);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks, can i process the String s in order to put something in a char?

Comment: (char)Integer.parseInt( s, 16 )

Answer (score 0):

resolved:

```
somma=(char) (somma%128);
```